# How can I speed up my Microsoft Project VBA code?

Tags: vba, userform, ms-project

I have a macro I use for Microsoft Project that loops through each task in the project, and performs several checks to find any problems with the tasks. These checks include several `IF` and `Select Case` statements. When dealing with large projects with more tasks, the macro can get lengthy. Is there anything I can do to improve the speed up the macro? I have already turned off screen updating and manual calculation.

Comment: If you haven't already, don't use ".select" anywhere if possible, that can slow it down.

Comment: You might consider posting the code at Stack Exchange's code review for more specific instructions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think speeding up a VBA code is based on your: Code & Environment, So please add your code and your environment ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off screen updating and setting calculation mode to Manual are the only application settings you can use to improve performance; the rest depends on your algorithm.

Your description of the problem is a bit vague: How large are your projects and how long does the macro take? If your projects are 1,000 tasks and you are making a dozen checks and your code takes more than five minutes, then yes, there is surely room for improvement. But if it's 20,000 tasks and 50 checks and the macro takes two minutes, stop trying to improve it--that's great performance.

Bottom line: it is impossible to tell if there is room for improvement without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same property (e.g. objTask.Start) in several different comparisons in your code then set the property into a local variable once and then perform your comparisons on the local variable.

For example:

**Slow code:**

```
If objTask.start < TestDate1 and objTask.Start > TestDate2 then ...
```

**Fast code:**

```
Define dteStart as Date 

dteStart = objTask.Start

if dteStart < TestDate1 and dteStart > testdate2 then ...
```

Calls to the `COM` object model are expensive. The second code example will be quite a bit faster (although as noted by Rachel above) it really does depend on the volume of data being processed.

Also, make sure you define your variables with appropriate types as relying on the default Variant data type is very slow.

Answer (score -2):

if you have some variables with lot of data like collections think about setting it to nothing and the end of your function

Set TasksCollection=Nothing

Comment: [When Are You Required To Set Objects To Nothing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx)

Comment: just to release the memory